# Is it possible to tame the change notifications each reboot from Mountain Lion Server?

Tags: macos, osx-server, notifications

I have Server.app installed on 10.8.1. The only service that is configured is file sharing. No DNS, no OD. After every single reboot I get a push notification and email with the following:

> Network change notification for computername
>
> The host name of uptown has changed to computername.local. Some services may not work correctly until they have been updated to use the new configuration.

The hostname has not changed. I logged in as an admin and set the hostname with `dscl --set HostName` and the issue persists. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.1 Server does exactly the same thing. I went and had lunch earlier, came back and had multiple email messages like this. Annoying, to say the least.

Comment: I hv tried using changeip to change the hostname, and I thought it would be a permanent change. But the issue still persists. Can you try this to see whether it will fix for u?
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3360452?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Confirmed that using changeip does not resolve the issue. The command runs and returns as expected but the issue persists.